# How to create a mutilevel side menu in ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to create multilevel side menu in my ionic app.
My current code is:

menu.html:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
<ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">

  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu side="left">
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-icon-left" menu-close href="#/app/ProSum">
        <i class="icon ion-android-clipboard" ></i>Profile Summary
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-icon-left" menu-close href="#/app/AspDash">
      <i class="icon ion-easel" ></i>Aspirations Dashboard
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-icon-left" menu-close href="#/app/Profile">
      <i class="icon ion-android-contact" ></i>Profile
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-icon-left" menu-close href="#/app/SignOut">
      <i class="icon ion-log-out" ></i>Sign Out
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

When I click on any option, more options list should be displayed.

Profile Summary

- Option 1
- Option 2

Profile

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3